# using tasks and blockingcollections for neverending tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, task, blockingcollection

I'm looking to read data off the wire and send it to a function to parse the contents. Due to the potential varying size of the message (xml), I could read a whole message, more than one message, or a message portion.

I am trying to implement code using the `BlockingCollection` where I would call `TryAdd` when I read the data off the wire and use a consumer thread to pull the data off the `BlockingCollection` to parse.  The examples seem pretty straight-forward, but they only seem to work once, then exit. I want the consumer to continuously parse as messages come in. See code below for what i am currently doing.

handling of messages:

```
    private static BlockingCollection<byte[]> queue = new BlockingCollection<byte[]>();

    public XmlHandler()
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
      {
          if (Console.ReadKey().KeyChar == 'c')
              cts.Cancel();
      });


        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => ParserWorker(queue, cts.Token));

    }
    //run producer
    public void AddData(byte[] data, int bytesRead)
    {
        bool success = false;
        try
        {
            success = queue.TryAdd(data);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Add loop canceled.");
            queue.CompleteAdding();
        }

        if (success)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" Add:{0}", data);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(" AddBlocked");
        }

        System.Console.WriteLine("queue count = " + queue.Count);
    }

    private static void ParserWorker(BlockingCollection<byte[]> bc, CancellationToken ct)
    {
        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        String xmlString;

        while (!bc.IsCompleted)
        {
            byte[] nextItem;
            try
            {

                if (!bc.TryTake(out nextItem, 0, ct))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(" Take Blocked");
                }
                else
                {
                    xmlString = encoder.GetString(nextItem, 0, nextItem.Length);
                    System.Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
                }

            }

            catch (OperationCanceledException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Taking canceled.");
                break;
            }
        }       
    }
```

Reading off the wire (this runs in a thread):

```
private void HandleClientComm(object client)
{
      TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
      NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

      byte[] message = new byte[8192];
      int bytesRead;

      while (true)
      {
          bytesRead = 0;

          try
          {

              bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
              byte[] temp = new byte[bytesRead];
              Array.Copy(message, temp, bytesRead);

              /*CODE WILL HANG HERE...*/
              ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
              String xmlString = encoder.GetString(message, 0, message.Length);
              System.Console.WriteLine(xmlString);
              /*DOES NOT GO BEYOND LINE ABOVE */

              handler.AddData(message, bytesRead);  //xmlhandler
           }
           catch (Exception e)
           {
               System.Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
               break;
           }

           if (bytesRead == 0)
           {
               break;
           }
      }
}
```

So can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What does "work once, then exit" means? Does the program exit or the while loop?

Comment: In my case, it writes the xml string 1 time, and then i fail to add more data to the queue.  If i don't start up the ParserWorker, then the code continues to add to the queue.  I don't know if the code is just blocked within in the Parserworker, or once bc.iscompleted goes true and the task exits.

Comment: Can you add the code which executes `XmlHandler`?

Comment: edited with handling of message off of the stream.

Comment: Does the stream keep reading? Or is it blocked waiting for more input after the first read?

Comment: actually, so far, it looks like my program is hanging on the writelines that i'm trying to do (in a simplified version of what i posted above)

Comment: It appears that my code to output to the console window is what is freezing.  Otherwise, everything seems to run fine.

Comment: You see the writes to the console hanging your app?

Comment: Can you post the simplified version?

Comment: @KyleW - see edited code.  My messages can be easily at the 4096 limit

Comment: If you cancel `Console.WriteLine` , does the code continue to execute correctly?

Comment: It seems to run okay.  i have other issues, but if i don't write to the console, it appears to continue to run.